# Floating Points PHP - MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, floating-point

Heey all!
I'm having troubles with storing floating points within MongoDB.

Within PHP i'm creating an Object which has a float property.
This could be such an object:
[image: cpuArray]

the property load is a valid float type within PHP.
Whenever i persist my data to Mongo it gets inserted like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("574d55d1da461e77030041aa"),
  "hostname": "VPS",
  "timestamp": NumberLong(1464685936),
  "cpuCores": NumberLong(2),
  "cpuList": {
    "cpu1": {
      "load": 2.2999999999999998224
    },
    "cpu2": {
      "load": 3.0
    }
  }
}
```

What causes this?
I'm using the following software + version:

- Mongo php extension version: 1.6.14
- Symfony version: 3.0.6
- MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4

I'm inserting the data using doctrine odm.

As I see within this post: [Mongodb PHP - Integers with decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006077/mongodb-php-integers-with-decimals) the decimals inserted in the database are correctly inserted and shown. For me this isn't.

Comment: Mandatory lecture: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the app i'm using to show the contents of my database has issues with showing it correctly. I've looked the value up through the mongoshell and it was exactly the value i've entered.